# How do I classify photos with Teachable Machine and Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, p5.js, tensorflow.js

I am a beginner with a little Javascript experience, but I am completely new to tenserflow.js.

My idea for a program seems simple enough but I need help executing it.

Basically what this program would do is:
Take the first image in a folder of hundreds. (named in the format 00001.png or something similar)
Classify it with a Teachable Machine Model (For example a model trained to tell if a photo is of a coffee cup or not)
If Teachable Machine says with confidence that it is a coffee cup, it would copy that file into a new folder.
Start over with the next image. The result would be a file with only photos of coffee cups.

I've taken a look at "The Coding Train's" video on youtube where he makes the emoji of the item show up on the screen. I've followed along and taken apart his code. Its a very nice tutorial but I am confused about how to expand on it. He uses the webcam and I want to use files on my PC.

I can train the model fine, I just get a little lost when I am outside my prossesing.js comfort zone. Any help is greatly appreciated! I am so excited by the potential of AI and I am eager to learn how to put my ideas to work.

link to coding train's video https://youtu.be/kwcillcWOg0

Answer (score 1):

I think processing runs in the browser so you won't be able to move local files around.
Nodejs if you want to stay with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate files on your local machine or some server you would have to use TensorFlow.js via Node.js which is also possible!

However Teachable Machine may not support Node.js environment - you would need to ask them about that. I think they only support browser.

In which case check out the code lab on how to make teachable machine which you can then just code in Node.js version of tensorflow and use that instead.  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-teachablemachine-codelab/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0